# shell script to monitor Disk IO not working properly

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, awk

I'm to monitor Disk IO using sar command, requirement is in output 
1) if %busy is above 80% for any disk, disk name & value should displayed in 1st line if all disk are below threshold then output should just display 'ok'
2) if %busy is above 60% but below 80% for any disk, disk name & value should displayed in 2nd line if all disk are below threshold then output should just display 'ok'

I've prepared below script but its not working properly is display some disk not found error for 1 disk and just display's 'ok'

can you please help me to fix my script and help me to achieve my goal

here is my script

```
`bash-3.00$ cat diskio.sh

 #!/bin/bash
a=`sar -d 2 2 |sed -n '/Average/,$ {s/Average//g;p;}'`
e=`$a|awk 'NR> 1{ if ($2 >80)  { print $1, $2; f=1; }  }  
    END { if (!f) print "ok" }'`
w=`$a|awk 'NR> 1{ if ($2 <80 && $2 >60)  { print $1, $2; f=1; }  }
    END { if (!f) print "ok" }'`
echo $e
echo $w`
```

below is output

```
`bash-3.00$ diskio.sh
./diskio.sh: line 3: hdisk18:  command not found.
./diskio.sh: line 4: hdisk18:  command not found.
ok
ok`
```

TIA
regards,
tnt5273

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use parentheses `$(code)` instead of back tics and `echo` or `<<<` to get the variable:

```
e=$(awk 'NR>1 {if ($2>40) {print $1,$2; f=1}} END {if (!f) print "ok"}' <<<"a$")
```

```
e=$(echo "$a" | awk 'NR>1 {if ($2>40) {print $1,$2; f=1}} END {if (!f) print "ok"}')
```

And always use double quote around variable: `echo $a` wrong, `echo "$a"` ok

Comment: thx very much jotne my script is now working properly ...time for beer pls join me..both of you :)

Answer (score 2):

You should put an `echo` before `$a` in the following two lines:

```
e=`$a|awk 'NR> 1{ if ($2 >40)  { print $1, $2; f=1; }  }  
END { if (!f) print "ok" }'`
w=`$a|awk 'NR> 1{ if ($2 <40 && $2 >20)  { print $1, $2; f=1; }  }
END { if (!f) print "ok" }'`
```

Such that they look like this:

```
e=`echo $a|awk 'NR> 1{ if ($2 >40)  { print $1, $2; f=1; }  }  
END { if (!f) print "ok" }'`
w=`echo $a|awk 'NR> 1{ if ($2 <40 && $2 >20)  { print $1, $2; f=1; }  }
END { if (!f) print "ok" }'`
```

Currently you just have `$a` which starts with `hdisk18`, and `bash` interperets it as a command, whilst what you want to do is echo the value held in `$a` and pipe this to `awk`.

Comment: thx imp25 error has gone now but i dont see any disks with values, when i run command manually it shows lot of disk's, for testing i've reduced my thresholds to 20 & 40, seems like its not processing data from a variable, i'm just getting ok ok in output, any idea?

Comment: Yes, see the comment in my post about double quote `"`